# Why doesn't the gallery work?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to make a simple JS image viewer all it needs to do is change the image source for my mainImage to the source of an image I click on from the gallery. for some reason it doesn't work any ideas? I just left the css in that is necessary for you to view the gallery that's why it looks a bit crazy. When I paste the code in here and click on the image it gives me an error which I'm guessing is the problem. Also ignore the fact that the link for the jscript is missing as I just put it inline to rule out that it just wasn't comminucation properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
here's a link to the page as it stands now it's in very early dev so it's not very good http://stevengamedev.com/page5.html

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#containerImg{
 width:100%; 
 position: fixed; 
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}

#Gallery{
 width:100%;
 position: fixed; 
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: -7;
 background-color:;
}

#padding{
 width:25%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:;
 float: left;
}

#padding2{
 width:18.75%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: ;
 float: left;
}

#boundry{
 background-color: ;
 width:50%;
 right: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: auto;
 align-content: center;
}

#mainImage{
 float:left;
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65) ;
 align-content: center;
}

#imagedescription{
 color: white;
}

#contentcontainerimage{
 width:75%;
 margin-left: 25%;  
 height:100%;
 z-index: 2; 
 float: left;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background-color: ;
 z-index: inherit;
}

#Gallerybounds{
 float: left;
 height: auto;
 z-index: inherit;
}

#Imagebounds{
 float:left;
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: ;
 z-index: inherit;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
}

#Imagebounds img{
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.gallery{
 
}

.imgStyle{
 margin:auto;
 align-content: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Steven game design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Image.css"/>
<link type="text/javascript" href=""/>
</head>
<div id="navigation">
<div id="navcontent">
<div id="icon">
 <img src="images/softwares/nav.png">
</div>
<div id="bodycontainer">
 <div class="navigationbody"></div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="home.html">Home</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="page2.html">About</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="page3.html">Blog</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="page4.html">Videos</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="page5.html">Pictures</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navigationbody">
 <a href="page6.html">Contact</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<body>
 <div id="Gallery">
 <div id="padding"></div>
 <div id="padding2"></div>
  <div id="boundry"> 
  <div id="mainImage"><img id ="mainImg" src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" alt="bridge" width="100%" height="auto">
  <div id="imagedescription">
  <h1>description!</h1>
  <a>this is a description of the picture etc! lots more words need more words words words words words words.</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
 </div> 
  </div>
 <div id="containerImg">
  
  <div id="contentcontainerimage">
  <div id="Gallerybounds">
  <div id="Imagebounds" onClick="changeImage(event)">
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/Blog/help6.png" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  <img  src="images/background/bridge4.jpg" width="90%" height="auto"/>
  
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
   
   var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
   
   if (targetElement.tagName == IMG){
   document.getElementById("mainImg").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `IMG` in `https://standards.usa.gov/`?

Comment: Your code is updating the "src" attribute of the "mainImage" `<div>` element instead of  the "mainImg" `<img>` tag.

Comment: Additionally, I believe `IMG` should be a string, not a variable.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at image-gallery libraries, some options : [blueimp-imagegallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) , [lightgallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js)

Comment: Thanks I fixed that and it's still not working though? here's the link to the page if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping IMG in either double or single quotation marks so the if statement condition reads:

```
if (targetElement.tagName == 'img') {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
}
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple thanks so much this has been really annoying me.

Comment: No problem at all. FYI, it was interpreting IMG as a variable as it wasn't wrapped in quotation marks. As you hadn't defined IMG as a variable it caused the error you saw. Wrapping IMG in quotation marks creates what's known as a 'string' — this is what you needed to compare against in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I'll know for next time Much appreciated.